# Vanilla JS hide Div if contains a string

Tags: javascript

I'm dealing with a CMS that sometimes returns error codes when displaying products.

I'm currently learning basic JS, searched all over stack overflow, and couldn't find an answer applicable.

[On this page](https://www.mapei.com/ca/en-ca/projects/project-detail/avenir-centre)

In the products used section, there is an error code for "#ResourceNotFound: ProjectResources, inside#
New Construction : No" that keeps appearing for every product.

Is there an easy way that javascript can be used to hide these snippets from the front end?

The codes I used to try was

```
document.querySelectorAll('.text-medium').forEach((element, index) => {
   if (element.innerText.includes('New Construction :  No')) {
       element.style.display = 'none';
   }
})
```

Comment: A bit outside the scope of your question, certainly, but why not investigate and rectify why these errors are appearing in the first place?

Comment: What went wrong when you tried it? Did you get an error, or did it just not work?

Comment: It didn't work.

And the reason why i'm not asking to investigate, is that it's usually an external dev team that deals with the back end of things and they're swamped with requests right now. Might take a while to get back since it's not a big priority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check for the presence of either of those phrases, as they are in separate `<div>` elements. Also, use `textContent` instead of `innerText`.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.text-medium').forEach((element, index) => {
   if (element.textContent.includes('New Construction :  No')
    || element.textContent.includes('#ResourceNotFound: ProjectResources')) {
       element.style.display = 'none';
   }
})
```

Comment: Thanks!

I tried adding the text, and it still does not work.

There is another issue. If i inspect the text-medium element, the string returned is technically:

"

                                            #ResourceNotFound: ProjectResources, inside#
                                        "
Not only: "#ResourceNotFound: ProjectResources, inside#"

I tried adding both and that section still appears on the live site.

Comment: I put it in the header so the code runs when the page loads.

Comment: You need to put it before the end of the body tag.

Comment: I also added a code module at the end of the doc to try if it will work - which it didn't unfortunately.

Comment: @BoPa That's strange. Are these elements being added after the document is loaded? This code works when I paste it into the console.

Comment: It worked. I put it in the middle of the page. When I put it at the bottom, it did not work. And in the head either.

Edit: Tried upvoting your answer, but  because i don't have enough reputation it didn't accept. You're awesome. Thanks again!